# Remove Jobs and Teams from Stack Overflow

Tags: script, greasemonkey, stackoverflow, jobs

### About

Removes all Jobs- and Teams-related stuff from Stack Overflow, keeping the main focus on Q/A.

Inspired by [this Meta Stack Overflow post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373797/can-features-not-related-to-qa-be-disabled)

#### Download

[View Source](https://github.com/a-stone-arachnid/SO-Userscripts/blob/master/no-more-jobs.user.js) or [Download](https://github.com/a-stone-arachnid/SO-Userscripts/raw/master/no-more-jobs.user.js) from GitHub.

#### Platform

Tested with Greasemonkey on Firefox. Should work in compatible userscript managers like Tampermonkey and Violentmonkey.

### Contact

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) or [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)? Comment on here or [raise an issue](https://github.com/a-stone-arachnid/SO-Userscripts/issues) on GitHub.

### Code

Written in jQuery and CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Changelog

#### 1.3.2

- Now blocks the <kbd>Products</kbd> button and the banner above the answer field encouraging people to use Teams

#### 1.2.0

- Now blocks the job ad above the "Hot Network Questions".

#### 1.1.0

- Moved most of code into a `<style>` instead of `$(...).hide()`ing each element to improve performance.